# Ellipsis not showing as hyperlink in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to create an ellipsis that when the string length is more than 200, it displays ... and when it is clicked the remaining text are displayed.
I was able to show the ellipsis ..., but the issue I have is that:

1. Its not displaying as hyperlink
2. How do I update the function I wrote to be able to display the remaining text when ... is clicked

This is the function

```
        public static string DisplayText(this string str, int charallowed)
    {
        if (str.Length > charallowed)
            return str.Substring(0, charallowed) + " ....";
        return str;
    }
```

**View**

```
@Html.Raw(@BPP.CCSP.Admin.Web.Helpers.ClipText.DisplayText(item.OPTION_VALUE, 200))
```

This is the result I have presently

[image: ellipsis]

Please what do  I do.

1. To display it as hyperlink
2. update the function I wrote to be able to display the remaining text when ... is clicked

Comment: If it is a link and when user clicks on that you want to show the remaining text or the navigation should happens ( like a normal link click) ? Your code is not producing the html markup for an anchor tag at all

Comment: I only wrote a function to truncate the string, I dont know how to make it display the remaining one. Please how do I do it. Also how do I make it have hyperlink